I am facing these error while executing build.yml in AWS codebuild
Error response from daemon: login attempt to ***/v2/ failed with status: 403 Forbidden
[Container] 2024/08/03 09:13:53.450561 Command did not exit successfully echo "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME" --password-stdin "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL" exit status 1
[Container] 2024/08/03 09:13:53.453890 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2024/08/03 09:13:53.453909 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: echo "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME" --password-stdin "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL". Reason: exit status 1
I did check docker credentials
I check the build.yml file if i am doing some syntax error but there is no syntax errorc

401 = Incorrect Authentication Details i.e. username/password etc.
403 = Authentication Failed, but this User doesn't have Permissions to do what they are trying to do
Hope that helps point you in the right direction for debugging your application further.

Can you give me little more in this
